# How to make binary variables for multiple individuals in a certain cell?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am dealing with a bit of a wonky data frame. I'm working with a standard tabular data set/.csv file that is fairly standard for the most part, however, in one column every observation is a list of individuals. Here's how it looks:

```
Layer       Grade              Players
Top           A         NY 08; NY 27; NY 80
Bottom        D         MA 27; MA 45; MA 65
Middle        B         NY 09; MA 48; NY 66
...
```

As you can see, the data frame is standard except for the Players column. How could I add a column for each player that provides a binary indicator of whether or not they were in the game? I would like the above data frame to become this:

```
Layer       Grade       Players                       NYAL 08     NYAL 27     NYAL 80    MAAC 27
Top           A         NYAL 08; NYAL 27; NYAL 80       1           1           1          0
Bottom        D         MAAC 27; MAAC 45; MAAC 65       0           0           0          1
Middle        B         NYAL 08; MAAC 48; NYAL 66       1           0           0          0
...
```

And so on.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `cSplit_e` from `splitstackshape`.  It would get the output in a compact way in a single line

```
library(splitstackshape)
out <- cSplit_e(df1, 'Players', sep=";", type = "character", fill = 0)
out
```

-output

```
#Layer Grade             Players Players_MA 27 Players_MA 45 Players_MA 48 Players_MA 65 Players_NY 08 Players_NY 09 Players_NY 27
#1    Top     A NY 08; NY 27; NY 80             0             0             0             0             1             0             1
#2 Bottom     D MA 27; MA 45; MA 65             1             1             0             1             0             0             0
#3 Middle     B NY 09; MA 48; NY 66             0             0             1             0             0             1             0
#  Players_NY 66 Players_NY 80
#1             0             1
#2             0             0
#3             1             0
```

If we want to remove the prefix in column names

```
names(out)[-(1:3)] <- sub('Players_', '', names(out)[-(1:3)])
```

---

Or another option is `mtabulate`

```
cbind(df1, mtabulate(strsplit(df1$Player, ";\\s+")))
```

-output

```
#   Layer Grade             Players MA 27 MA 45 MA 48 MA 65 NY 08 NY 09 NY 27 NY 66 NY 80
#1    Top     A NY 08; NY 27; NY 80     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     1
#2 Bottom     D MA 27; MA 45; MA 65     1     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
#3 Middle     B NY 09; MA 48; NY 66     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Layer = c("Top", "Bottom", "Middle"), Grade = c("A", 
"D", "B"), Players = c("NY 08; NY 27; NY 80", "MA 27; MA 45; MA 65", 
"NY 09; MA 48; NY 66")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: I tried the 'splitstackshape' approach, but I am getting this error: 'Error in rep(seq.int(len), vapply(listOfValues, length, integer(1L))) : 
  invalid 'times' argument'
Any thoughts?

Comment: @rogues77 is the error based on the same data i.e. the one I showed in my post or on different post

Comment: @rogues77 you could also try the `mtabulate` approach

Comment: Ah! You're right, I changed my code before running your solution and it screwed me up. My mistake. One more thing--is there any way to remove "Players_" from the new column names without deleting the initial 'players' column?

Comment: I actually used the mtabulate function, which works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this `tidyverse` approach with `separate_rows()` and `pivot_wider()` which will produce a close result to that you want:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
df2 <- df %>% mutate(Dup=Players) %>%
  separate_rows(Dup,sep = '; ') %>%
  mutate(id=1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Dup,values_from=id) %>%
  replace(is.na(.),0)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 12
  Layer  Grade Players   `NY 08` `NY 27` `NY 80` `MA 27` `MA 45` `MA 65` `NY 09` `MA 48` `NY 66`
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Top    A     NY 08; N~       1       1       1       0       0       0       0       0       0
2 Bottom D     MA 27; M~       0       0       0       1       1       1       0       0       0
3 Middle B     NY 09; M~       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       1       1
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Layer = c("Top", "Bottom", "Middle"), Grade = c("A", 
"D", "B"), Players = c("NY 08; NY 27; NY 80", "MA 27; MA 45; MA 65", 
"NY 09; MA 48; NY 66")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```